# redux persist in nextjs application and wrap with next-redux-wrapper

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit

I want to use redux-persist in the Nextjs application but it doesn’t work
here is my code store.ts and _app.tsx

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['auth'], // specify any reducers you want to persist here
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const createReduxStore = () => {
    const store = configureStore({
        reducer: persistedReducer,
        middleware: [thunk],
        devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    });
    return store;
};

export type ReduxStore = ReturnType<typeof createReduxStore>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<ReduxStore['getState']>;
export type AppDispatch = ReduxStore['dispatch'];
export type ReduxThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action>;
export const persistor = persistStore(createReduxStore());


export const reduxWrapper = createWrapper<ReduxStore>(createReduxStore, {debug: false});
```

and Also in _app.tsx we have this code

```
const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const reduxStore = useStore();

    return (
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
            <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default reduxWrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

what is the problem with this piece of code and how can we persist the data in redux when the page reload?

Comment: Hey, were you able to make it work?